# Xcode: Text Field to String

Tags: ios, string, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uitextview

I'm new to Xcode and trying to do something easy.
But unfortunately, I couldn't find an easy way to do so.
My question might be (laughably) easy but I'm seriously stuck right now.
In Xcode, there is an object in the object library called "Text Field".
In this text field, words can be entered. I want to push a button and save the written words not a string, which I can then display as a label.
Help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The "Text Field" UI element in the object library represents an instance of a `UITextField`. If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html), a text field has a `text` property - a `String` that contains the current textual content of the text field. Similarly, `UILabel` has a `text` property. So you want to take the text field's `text`, and assign it to the label's `text`.

Assuming you have an outlet to your text field in the storyboard and an outlet/variable referencing the label you want to set the text of, in your button's action method, you might do something like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(button: UIButton) {
    myLabel.text = myTextField.text
}
```